# Regular expression for a string ends with \

Tags: c#

i am new for regular expression .i want to validate the path like this 
`d:\` or `d:\test\` or `d:\test\test\` or `d:\test\test\test\test\`

it should always end with `\`

i tried this but does not work for my purpose `^([a-zA-Z]:)?(\\[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+)+\\?`

Comment: Why have you got a `?` at the end when you've said you want it to *definitely* end with a backslash? You should probably use a dollar as well to signify the end of the string...

Comment: Are you sure, you don't want to work with [System.IO.Path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.io.path.aspx)?

Comment: Why not just `if (!path.EndsWith("\\")) handleError();`

Comment: `^([a-zA-Z]:)?\\([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+\\)+$`

Comment: are you using a RegularExpresion because you need to restrict the characters allowed for a path ?do you need to check that the path exists ?

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick for you:

```
bool result = Regex.IsMatch(yourstring, @"\\$");
```